# Is there a way to create tag synonyms in a JIRA board/project?

Tags: jira

I am not an expert in JIRA and I've stumbled upon a problem with tagging issues.

We are working on a mobile app and I was tagging the iOS App related issues with "iOS", and I've found out that my coworker is using the tag "IOS" (capital i). I try to correct those tags whenever I can but I was wondering if there is a way to create a tag synonym (similar to here on Stack Exchange) where "IOS" will also be considered as "iOS"?

Comment: Why don't you use the component field instead of a label ? seems like a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you were asking for, but one approach would be:

1. Do a JQL search for all issues having the IOS issue (labels = "IOS")
2. Go to Tools->Bulk Change->All {#} issues
3. Select all issues->Next
4. Choose 'Edit Issues'->Next
5. Select Change Labels->Add to Existing->"iOS"->Next
6. Confirm.
7. Repeat steps 1-4
8. Select Change Labels->Find and Remove These->"IOS"->Next
9. Confirm.
10. Tell your co-worker to stop using IOS and use iOS instead.

Not 100% since I haven't tried it, but it *should* work.

Comment: This definitely should work, and I'll try it now. but in the meantime, I'm really investigating ways to automatically map one tag to other, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a JQL to lowercase all tag names (I thought they were case insensitive--shows how little I know) and then all tags that are otherwise the same, but for case, will be rendered the same. Long live "ios" ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Labels (or tags) in many systems (blogs, StackExchange too I suppose) are meant to be in loose form, user-generated rather than administrated.

Perhaps you should try using [Components](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/managing-components-861253335.html) in JIRA instead to get back more control over it?